# Building static library weird error in XCode 4

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to build a *static library* but i get compile-time errors such as: `Unknown type name UIImage` or  `Unknown type name CGSize`.

I have added both **UIKit** and **CoreGraphics** frameworks to `Link Binary With Libraries`. 
What am I doing wrong ??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it's compile time errors then it's nothing to do with the libraries you're linking against. This error sounds very much like you haven't included the UIKit headers. Make sure that you have `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` in the files that you're using `UIImage` and `CGSize` in.

Answer (score 0):

The libraries are relevant during the linking phase only. For the compilation, the `import` statements are relevant.

Most likely you are missing:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```